# Mains switch or circuit breaker to turn off at zero voltage, for the home

Tags: electrical, switch

I want a switch for mains electricity in my house. A switch that I can turn on and off as any normal switch, but that turns itself off when there is no power. The intended use is for a vanity unit that has bright lights. These lights would only work if the main room light is on. When the room light is turned off then the vanity lights would turn off. When the main room light is turned back on then the vanity lights would remain off.

Similar switches are available for workshop equipment, such as lathes and table saws. They are intended as safety switches so the equipment does not turn on after a power cut. I am interested in whether similar switches are available in the UK with conventional domestic format and, if they are, what are they called and where can I find them?

Given the UK electrical regulations I would get a qualified electrician to do the installation. But I want to understand what is available or possible.

Comment: @Tester101 He is asking about a relay setup. We should be able to explain this without specific product promotion.

Comment: I fail to see how this is not a "shop for me" type question. You're listing the qualities you want in a product, and go as far as to ask where you can find them. That surely sounds like you're asking us to shop for you. It could also be closed as off topic, since you're not doing the work yourself. However, it seems as though others disagree with me, so I will let the community decide.

Comment: @Tester101 Thank you for reopening the question. Yes I am listing what I want it to do and I have said I want to know what to call the device, if such exists. That is so I can search for it. All my searches so far have been unsuccessful. As I also said, given the UK electrical regulations I will not be dong the work myself. However I would like to know about the possibilities so I can correctly direct a qualified electrician.

Comment: If you have to direct the Electrician, I wouldn't say he's *qualified*.